# Add to apple wallet demo fails

Tags: ios, passkit, apple-wallet

I'm trying to use Apple wallet to permit users for a coupon usage so I followed apple demo
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PassKit_PG/YourFirst.html)

when it comes to  this part

### To get the signpass tool, do the following:

- Download this book’s companion file (from [The developer downloads area](https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/iOS/Wallet_Support_Materials/WalletCompanionFiles.zip)), and locate the signpass project.
- Open the project in Xcode, and build it.
- Right-click on the signpass executable (in the Products folder in Xcode) and select Show in Finder.
- Move the signpass executable to the Documents folder.

When  i  try to run the demo project i got this error

```
usage:  signpass -p <rawpass> [-o <path>] [-c <certSuffix>]
    signpass -v <signedpass>

     -p Sign and zip a raw pass directory
     -v Unzip and verify a signed pass's signature and manifest. This DOES NOT validate pass content.
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

[image]

Any help is extremely appreciated